# An incorrect result of CDF

Tags: bugs, probability-or-statistics

In 13.3.1 on Windows 10 I execute

```
cdf = CDF[TransformedDistribution[\[Xi] + 
2*\[Mu], {\[Xi] \[Distributed] 
 BinomialDistribution[n, p], \[Mu] \[Distributed] 
 PoissonDistribution[\[Lambda]]}], t]
```

> `Piecewise[{{E^(-\[Lambda]), n > 0 && n - t < 0},  {(1 - p)^n/E^\[Lambda], (n == 0 && t >= 0) || (n > 0 && t == 0)},  {((1 - p)^(-1 - Floor[t])*((1 - p)^(1 + Floor[t]) -  (1 - p)^n*p^(1 + Floor[t])*Binomial[n, 1 + Floor[t]]* Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1 - n + Floor[t], 2 + Floor[t],  p/(-1 + p)]))/E^\[Lambda], n > 0 && t > 0 && n - t >= 0}}, 0]`

```
cdf /. {n -> 5, p -> 1/3, \[Lambda] -> 1, t -> 10}
```

> `1/E`

and, in order to check it by the definition of `CDF`,

```
Probability[\[Xi] + 2*\[Mu] <=  10, {\[Xi] \[Distributed] 
BinomialDistribution[n, p], \[Mu] \[Distributed] 
PoissonDistribution[\[Lambda]]}] /. {n -> 5, p -> 1/3, \[Lambda] -> 1}
```

> `27/(10 E)`

The latter contradicts the former. I think the latter is true. Before submitting a possible bug to WTS, I'd like to discuss with other users how to obtain the correct expression for this `CDF`.

Comment: Same results on a MacOS 11.7.10, MMA version 13.3.0.

Comment: @RomkeBontekoe: Thank you for your interest to the question and  your work.

Comment: The former is definitely wrong, which can easily be checked by experiment:
https://pastebin.com/mtZK1vFV

Comment: @flinty: Thank you.

Comment: My unsuccessful attempt is `DiscreteConvolve[PDF[BinomialDistribution[n, p], t], 
 PDF[TransformedDistribution[
   2*\[Mu], \[Mu] \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[\[Lambda]]], 
  t], t, x, Assumptions -> x <= n]` and `DiscreteConvolve[PDF[BinomialDistribution[n, p], t], 
 PDF[TransformedDistribution[
   2*\[Mu], \[Mu] \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[\[Lambda]]], 
  t], t, x, Assumptions -> x > n]`: both return the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that `CDF` is having trouble because `t` isn't restricted to non-negative integers and/or the specific values of the parameters need to be specified.  The following works:

```
parms = {n -> 5, p -> 1/3, λ -> 1};
dist = TransformedDistribution[ξ + 2*μ, 
  {ξ \[Distributed]  BinomialDistribution[n, p], 
  μ \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[λ]}] /. parms

Table[{t, CDF[dist /. parms, t],
   Probability[ξ + 2*μ <= t, 
    {ξ \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[n, p], 
     μ \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[λ]}] /. parms},
  {t, 0, 10}] // TableForm
```

[image: Matching CDF values]

**Addition**

Solving this with paper and pencil one finds the following:

```
pdf[t_, n_, p_, λ_] := Sum[Binomial[n, i] p^i (1 - p)^(n - i) Exp[-λ] λ^((t - i)/2)/((t - i)/2)!,
  {i, Boole[OddQ[t]], Min[t, n], 2}]; 
cdf[t_, n_, p_, λ_] := Sum[pdf[t0, n, p, λ], {t0, 0, t}]
```

Alternatively one can use probability generating functions.

```
(* Probability generating function of 2 X with X having a Poisson(λ) distribution *)
dist = TransformedDistribution[2 x, x \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[λ]]
pgf2 = Expectation[z^(2 x), x \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[λ]]
(* E^((-1 + z^2) λ) *)

(* Probability generating function of a binomial distribution *)
pgf1 = Expectation[z^x, x \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[n, p]]
(* (1 + p (-1 + z))^n *)

(* PGF of the sum *)
pgf = pgf1 pgf2
(* E^((-1 + z^2) λ) (1 + p (-1 + z))^n *)

(* Now obtain the pdf for the sum *)
pdf2[t_, n_, p_, λ_] := (D[E^((-1 + z^2) λ) (1 + p (-1 + z))^n, {z, t}]/t!) /. z -> 0
```

When specifying $t$ and $n$ `pdf` is faster than `pdf2`.  But when only `t` is specified `pdf2` will produce a symbolic result and `pdf` won't.

Comment: Isn't it my `Probability[\[Xi] + 2*\[Mu] <=  10, {\[Xi] \[Distributed] 
BinomialDistribution[n, p], \[Mu] \[Distributed] 
PoissonDistribution[\[Lambda]]}] /. {n -> 5, p -> 1/3, \[Lambda] -> 1}` , only for the range of values instead of `10`?

Comment: @user64494 I don't understand your question.

Comment: The correct expression for `CDF[TransformedDistribution[\[Xi] + 
2*\[Mu], {\[Xi] \[Distributed] 
 BinomialDistribution[n, p], \[Mu] \[Distributed] 
 PoissonDistribution[\[Lambda]]}], t]` is asked. You present `parms = {n -> 5, p -> 1/3, λ -> 1};
dist = TransformedDistribution[ξ + 2*μ, 
  {ξ \[Distributed]  BinomialDistribution[n, p], 
  μ \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[λ]}] /. parms`.( The substituion `/. parms` is superfluous.). Hope you feel the difference.

Comment: Not feelin' it.  It appears that the only currently "workable" (rather than "correct") expression has $t$ specified.  One can get symbolic results but only for specific values of $t$.  For example:  `cdf = CDF[TransformedDistribution[\[Xi] + 2*\[Mu], {\[Xi] \[Distributed]      BinomialDistribution[n, p], \[Mu] \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[\[Lambda]]}], 9] // FunctionExpand`.

Comment: I more or less clearly see how to write down the correct expression for `PDF[TransformedDistribution[\[Xi] +  2*\[Mu], {\[Xi] \[Distributed]   BinomialDistribution[n, p], \[Mu] \[Distributed]   PoissonDistribution[\[Lambda]]}], t]` by hand.

Comment: @user64494 Doing this "by hand" might currently be the only way to obtain a general answer.  Here are two functions that I hope are correct: `pdf[t_, n_, p_, \[Lambda]_] := 
 Sum[Binomial[n, i] p^i (1 - p)^(n - i) Exp[-\[Lambda]] \[Lambda]^((t - i)/2)/((t - i)/2)!, {i, 
   Boole[OddQ[t]], Min[t, n], 2}];
cdf[t_, n_, p_, \[Lambda]_] := Sum[pdf[t0, n, p, \[Lambda]], {t0, 0, t}]`.

Comment: Yes, something of that sort. Did you check your `cdf[t_, n_, p_, \[Lambda]_] `?

Comment: I accepted your "Solving this with paper and pencil" because this may be useful for Mathematica developers.

Answer (score 1):

```
    In[119]:= Clear[mgf]; 
    mgf[t_] := 
     MomentGeneratingFunction[
      dist = TransformedDistribution[
        x + 2*y, {x \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[n, p], 
         y \[Distributed] PoissonDistribution[\[Lambda]]}], t]
```

For discrete distributions we have:

ZTransform[PDF[dist, x], x, Exp[-y]] == mgf[y]

ZTransform[PDF[dist, x], x, y] == mgf[-Log[y]]

PDF[dist, x] == InverseZTransform[mgf[-Log[y]], y, x]

```
In[121]:= resPDF = InverseZTransform[mgf[-Log[y]], y, x];

In[123]:= resCDF = Sum[InverseZTransform[mgf[-Log[y]], y, x], {x, 0, t}];

In[124]:= resCDF /. {n -> 5, p -> 1/3, \[Lambda] -> 1, t -> 10}

Out[124]= 27/(10 E)
```

I will file a bug, thank you for catching this.

Comment: If one  uncovers `resPDF` and `resCDF`, then one sees the roots of some recurrent equation implicitly, not explicitly. This is not it.

Comment: Thank you for your report about the bug. I know several such bugs in `CDF`.